# Hide div if more that one class exists

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a div, but I only want to hide it if the class exists only once.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/30/

Here's the html

```
<button class="clone">Clone</button> 
<div id="upload_image_sets">
  <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
    <input type="text" id="upload_image_link_1" class="image" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="' . $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] . '" />
    <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <div class="actions">
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, i did write what div I wanted to hide and must of deleted it when i pasted the code, doh.

I'm trying to hide the remove button if it shows only once, i.e. if I clone a form and 2 forms exists, show the remove button, if only 1 form exists then hide the remove button.

Hopefully that makes it clearer.

Comment: You need to describe your problem clearly.It is unclear, which class exists only once ?

Comment: and maybe give a [sssce](http://www.sscce.org/) example

Comment: @mohammadadil the remove button should only work, if there is more than  one "div" on the page

Comment: I see 3 div's in your html.which one you are talking about ?

Comment: You mean to say if element with this class are more than one then only it should be hidden

Comment: @RaviKumar No the opposite, if the class exists more than once it should show, if it shows only once it should hide.

Comment: Check my answer i have also included the jsfiddle update. Hopefully this is what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $(".clonedInput").length > 1){
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
        $(this).show()
    } 
    if( $("button.remove").length < 2){
       $("button.remove").hide()
    } 
    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    });
});
if( $(".clonedInput").length > 1){
        $('button.remove').show();
    }else {
        $('button.remove').hide();
}
```

[**Update Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/53/)

Comment: But the remove button is there it is not hidden when there is only one div although it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can you just test $('.clonedInput').length
Delete only if there is more than one element delete

```
 if($('.clonedInput').length>1){
            $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
   }
```

Exemple
http://jsfiddle.net/n4g4q/

Answer (score 0):

I supose this is what you mean:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(".clonedInput").first().clone().show();//show because it may be hidden
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( $(".clonedInput").length > 1 ) {//when more than one
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    }
    else{
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").hide();//otherwise just hide
    }
    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/34/

Answer (score 0):

Thsi code should work -

```
$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
        var new_Input = $(".clonedInput").first().clone();
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);  
        //alert(cloneIndex);
        if(cloneIndex>1){
            $('button.remove').show();
        }
    });
    $(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;
        $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
        $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
            updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
        })
        //alert(cloneIndex);
        if(cloneIndex<=2){
            $('button.remove').hide();
        }
    });
```

I have also updated the fiddle it's exactly what you wanted here is the link -

http://jsfiddle.net/visittoravi/PqApF/2